# registry keys on servers not showing results

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Not too sure why the below is not working. Basically, there are multiple elseif statements based on the values of keys.

I tested a server with setting `$valuePassword` equal to random characters I put in and I also set `$valueAutoLogin` to `'1'`. But, the result I get is below which does not show anything?

Also - can you think of a better way of doing this instead of multiple elseif statments?

>

```
clear
Import-Module PSRemoteRegistry
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\MANNY\Servers.txt

foreach($computer in $computers)
{
Write-Host "Checking $computer"

#Check if key exists
$valuePassword = Get-RegValue -ComputerName $Computer -Key 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Value DefaultPassword
$valueAutoLogin = Get-RegValue -ComputerName $Computer -Key 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Value AutoAdminLogon


if($valuePassword -eq $null -and $valueAutoLogin -eq $null)
{Write-Host "$computer not set"}

elseif($valuePassword -notcontains $null -and $valueAutoLogin -eq $null)
{Write-Host "$computer has Password set"}

elseif($valuePassword -eq $null -and $valueAutoLogin -eq '1')
{Write-Host "$computer has Autologin set but not password"}

elseif($valuePassword -notcontains $null -and $valueAutoLogin -eq '1')
{Write-Host "$computer has Autologin set and password set - AUTOLOGIN IS POSSIBLY SET"}

}
```

>
RESULT:

```
Checking SV160666
Checking SV160668
Checking SV160670
Checking SV160672
Checking SV160674
Checking SV180435
Checking SV193865
Checking SV193885
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What result do you get when you try with builtin methods? Also, you should add an `else` branch to report unexpected values.

```
Get-Content "C:\MANNY\Servers.txt" | % {
  $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine", $_)
  $key = $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon")

  $valuePassword  = $key.GetValue("DefaultPassword")
  $valueAutoLogin = $key.GetValue("AutoAdminLogon")

  $key.Close()
  $reg.Close()

  if ($valuePassword -eq $null -and $valueAutoLogin -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "$_ not set"
  } elseif ($valuePassword -ne $null -and $valueAutoLogin -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "$_ has Password set"
  } elseif ($valuePassword -eq $null -and $valueAutoLogin -eq '1') {
    Write-Host "$_ has Autologin set but not password"
  } elseif ($valuePassword -ne $null -and $valueAutoLogin -eq '1') {
    Write-Host "$_ has Autologin set and password set - AUTOLOGIN IS POSSIBLY SET"
  } else {
    Write-Host "$_: unexpected AutoLogin value: $valueAutoLogin"
  }
}
```

Comment: interesting - that works - however, how would I get the output to show results per server? $computer is not working as it is not defined - if I define get-content as $computer it does not show any of the server names.

Comment: Copy/paste error on my part. Since I connected `Get-Content` and `ForEach-Object` with a pipe, `$computer` has to be replaced with `$_`. Fixed.